# Laravel deploy error with install doctrine/dbal

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error

```
The command "/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/tixy/releases/2/artisan migrate --force" failed.                          

  Exit Code: 1 (General error)                                                                                      

  Host Name: my server ip                                                                                         

  ================                                                                                                  
  [2018-07-24 15:19:05] production.ERROR: RuntimeException: Changing columns for table "messages" requires Doctrin  
  e DBAL; install "doctrine/dbal". in /var/www/html/tixy/releases/2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Databa  
  se/Schema/Grammars/Grammar.php:287
```

php version = 7.2
laraveel version = 5.2

I have done composer install separately on the server and it worked. but on deploying using `dep deploy` it fails with the response above

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error on Ubuntu 16.04 php 7.2 as well. When I run compose install, it did not work.

Instead I added `"doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",` manually to composer.json and run `composer update` and it worked fine.

You can give it a shot. Good luck

Comment: Still wouldn't work.....I added that to my composer file, dis composer update committed to my repo and did dep deploy...but still same error.

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 20.04 and php 7.4